# Is there any way to have a Batch file read motherboard and BIOS info automatically within standalone FreeDOS?

Tags: batch, freedos

I'm basically looking for a way to output a system's motherboard model (and possibly BIOS version, but that's just extra) so as to turn it into a variable to use in a batch file running in FreeDOS.

Some clarifications:

- Yes, it needs to be in FreeDOS or some other DOS-based OS that can be booted to from a USB.
- The process needs to be automatable using batch files.
- This is to be used on many different systems, all without any other OS

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!